# how to call codeigniter controller in wordpress on click

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter

I am implementing ecommerce project with combining wordpress and codigniter framwork, for static pages i am using worpress. Integrating Wp and CI according this [LINK](https://github.com/AdeptMarketing/Wordpress_CI) . now every thing working fine, on click of **cart icon** i need to load side view in Wordpress which is already done in CI. Using common header in both CI and WP.

How to call codeigniter controller function or how to load same view from CI in Wordpress?

I created separate header file loading header data from WP API and including that file in both CI and WP

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure about my suggestion is working or not,
 you can load the CodeIgniter page inside an iframe in a WordPress page, you can create a cart.php file in WordPress.

Comment: insted of side view  can redirect to cart view page with static CI cart page url, which is already implemented in CI?